# Good standing account can no longer ask questions on any IP address

Tags: support, questions, user-accounts, post-ban

While I don't have a lot of rep on Stack Overflow, I cannot find any where a reason as to why I am no longer able to ask questions.

I have 32 reputation points, and have not had any excessive amount of bad standing questions. I do not believe I have actually had **any** bad standing questions. The part I am confused about is that I have asked questions this week on the two IP addresses I use mainly, and none of the questions got downvotes. I am now unable to ask question at my work **or** my house.

I have read through other posts about the question block issues and things to fix them, but I am confused as to why I am unable to ask questions on my two IP addresses. Is there a measurable amount of rep that I can keep track of to fix this/how much I need? Could there be an issue that I am just overlooking? I am just concerned because I use Stack Overflow often and have a question I would like to ask about something I cannot find anything on.

I am a computer science major, so I am willing to do whatever I need to figure out this issue, as the site says making another account does not work.

Comment: Why do you think your account is in good standing (at least when it comes to questions)?

Comment: @Oded I guess I am not 100% sure because I do not know what calculates "good standing", but I have only received 5 total downvotes, but I believe all have been cancelled out by upvotes and are across different questions. I also don't know if the 5 downvotes relative to my 32 rep could be a percentage that is causing the "bad standing"?

Comment: If you don't know what it means, why use it and so extensively?

Answer (score 10):

You have not asked good questions.

From the 10 questions you have asked (6 of which are deleted - some of the deleted ones have been downvoted). Across all of these, there is just one that as a score of 1 - the remaining ones are either 0 or have a negative score. That's not well received questions and it deserves a question ban.

Comment: So then, if the ban is automatic, how did me asking a question that never got downvoted cause the ban? I guess this is where I am lost.

Comment: @spaff What makes you so sure that that's what cause the ban?  (It might have been, or it might not have been.)

Comment: I am at least sure of this because between the last time I asked my last question, I only received positive votes.

Comment: You are assuming that's what it was, @spaff - might have been you deleting a question. Deleting questions can cause one to fall into the ban.

Comment: Ahhh, I was not aware of that. I have deleted a couple questions (some that had no votes or downvotes) just to clear them out. Would undeleting all my questions, good and bad, possibly help this?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th - @spaff - that has everything you need to know.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will start working on it now.